# actualizar datos chartjs

Tags: laravel, chart.js

tengo un problema al querer actualizar un grafico de chartjs mediante un select que contiene los meses, al seleccionar otro mes para que actualice el gráfico me lo duplica y en vez de tener una barra me parecen dos y si hago otra selección me aparecen tres barras, lo que yo necesito es que al cambiar el select me actualice los datos del grafico en la barra que ya esta creada, dejo mi codigo a continuación ojalá me puedan ayudar.

Con este codigo traigo los datos y los dejo en un array.

getMaquinarias(){

```
            let me=this;


            var url=this.ruta + '/dashboardmaquianria2?idmes=' + me.idmes;

            axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
                var respuesta= response.data;
                me.arrayMotoniveladoras = respuesta.motoniveladoras;
                //cargamos los datos del chart
                 me.loadMaquinarias();

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
```

Y con el siguiente código genero el gráfico y quiero actualizarlo.

loadMaquinarias(){

```
             let me=this;

             me.arrayMotoniveladoras.map(function(x){
                me.varMesMaquinaria.push(x.nombre_centro);
                me.varTotalMaquinaria.push(x.total);
            });
            me.varMaquinaria=document.getElementById('motoniveladoras').getContext('2d');
            me.charMaquinaria = new Chart(me.varMaquinaria, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: me.varMesMaquinaria,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'COSTO',
                        data: me.varTotalMaquinaria,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 42, 0.5)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 42, 0.5)',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });

        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes destruir la grafica para que la vuelva a crear y no se sobreponga

```
if (window.myPie) {
   window.myPie.clear();
   window.myPie.destroy();
}
window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
```